scipy.signal.firls TypeError: _ArrayMemoryError.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dtype'
I have installed scipy 1.14.1. This code
fs = 44100
b = firls(numtaps = int(9e4)+1, bands = [0, 1.99, 2, fs/2], 
          desired = [1e-5, 1e-5, 1, 1], weight = [0.5, 1], fs = fs)

returns
File "...\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\_fir_filter_design.py", line 1083, in firls
    a = solve(Q, b, assume_a="pos", check_finite=False)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_basic.py", line 213, in solve
    anorm = lange(norm, a1)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: _ArrayMemoryError.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dtype'

I expected coefficients of FIR filter.

For completeness: which version of numpy are you using?

It looks like you are hitting a bug somewhere in the scipy/numpy code. Something is trying to raise the _ArrayMemoryError exception, but it is not passing in the correct arguments to the _ArrayMemoryError class.

On Linux, I get the error MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.1 GiB for an array with shape (45001, 45001) and data type float64. I think that means you can't design a filter this big using the memory you have. It's strange that you don't get a MemoryError, though.

@NickODell, yeah, that's the exception that is generated when numpy._core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError is raised with the correct parameters passed to _ArrayMemoryError (that is, a shape and a dtype).  A TypeError like the one shown above can be generated with a statement such as raise numpy._core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError((10, 10)) (the dtype parameter is missing).  The mystery is how and where such a call is being made.
